# Unable to POST to Server using RestKit

Tags: objective-c, restkit, afnetworking, restkit-0.20

I have been trying this for quite sometime now, but I just couldn't be able to post successfully to my server. I have read [this](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#post-patch-and-delete-an-object), [github object mapping overview for the Restkit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) and, the [Gist restKit tutorial](https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md).

**My Problem**

I am trying to post sign in information(nickname,hardwareId,phone model) and get the AccountId from my server. But I am getting this response from the console:

```
GuessTheImage[6832:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<AccountsClass 0x8c5cba0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key AccountInfo.'
```

**What I think is the problem**

I believe I am messing up the way I store the data right before the mapping part. But I am not sure where exactly.

**The JSON that I am trying post should look like this**

```
{
  "DeviceType": "sample string 1",
  "HardwareId": "sample string 2",
  "NickName": "sample string 3",
  "AccountId": 4
}
```

**Overview of the program**
I created the variables for mapping in the AccountClass. From loginviewcontroller, I get the device type, hardwareId and nickname after the user clicks login button and assign those variables to the variables in AccountClass and map it POST if afterwards.
AccountClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AccountsClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong,retain)NSString *DeviceType;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSNumber *AccountId;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *NickName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *HardwareId;

@end
```

LoginViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *submitButton;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSUUID *identifierForVendor;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *model;
@property (nonatomic,readonly,retain)NSString *StoreIdentifierForVendor;
@property (nonatomic,readonly,retain)NSString *StoreTheModel;
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *nickname;
@end
```

LoginViewController.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "AccountsClass.h"
@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize usernameTextField;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dissmissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [usernameTextField setDelegate:self];


}
-(void)loadPostRequest
{
    _StoreIdentifierForVendor = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
    _StoreTheModel = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    _nickname = usernameTextField.text;
     AccountsClass *AccountInfo = [[AccountsClass alloc] init];
    AccountInfo.NickName = _nickname;
    NSNumberFormatter *hardwareIdentification = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [hardwareIdentification setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
    NSNumber *hwreID =[hardwareIdentification numberFromString:_StoreIdentifierForVendor];
    AccountInfo.HardwareId = hwreID;
    AccountInfo.DeviceType =_StoreTheModel;
      RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[AccountsClass class]];
   [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"NickName", @"HardwareId", @"DeviceType",@"AccountId"]];

    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); // Anything in 2xx
    RKResponseDescriptor *AccountDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:statusCodes];


    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping]; // objectClass == NSMutableDictionary
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"AccountInfo.NickName", @"AccountInfo.HardwareId", @"AccountInfo.DeviceType",@"AccountInfo.AccountId"]];
    // For any object of class Article, serialize into an NSMutableDictionary using the given mapping and nest
    // under the 'article' key path
    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[AccountInfo class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://picquiz.azurewebsites.net"]];
                                [manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
                                [manager addResponseDescriptor:AccountDescriptor];
                                // POST to create
                                [manager postObject:AccountInfo path:@"/Accounts" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];

}
-(void)dissmissKeyboard
{
    [usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
    [self loadPostRequest];
}
@end
```

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you show the JSON that you expect to receive back from the server in response to the POST please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be:

```
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"AccountInfo.NickName", @"AccountInfo.HardwareId", @"AccountInfo.DeviceType",@"AccountInfo.AccountId"]];
```

because the data that you are trying to POST doesn't have nested data like that. It looks like it should be:

```
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"NickName", @"HardwareId", @"DeviceType",@"AccountId"]];
```

Comment: Thanks again Wain with your brilliant response. I did try switching places of request mapping with response mapping before, but it didn't work before. I might had tried something else all together.